# Laravel Many to Many not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a basic many to many relationship:

```
Posts
Tags
```

I have a pivot table called `post_tag`.

I am trying tor return all of a given posts tags in my view file as such:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

    {{ dd($post->tags)  }}

@endforeach
```

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.post_id'
>   in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tags` where `tags`.`post_id` =
>   1 and `tags`.`post_id` is not null) (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\laravel\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)

Here are my models:

```
class Post extends Model
{
   ....

    public function tags() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Tag::class);
    }

}


class Tag extends Model
{
  ....

    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Post::class);
    }

}
```

Any ideas as to whats going on here? I have data in the pivot table but it seems like the relations are not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use belongsToMany for both relations

```
class Post extends Model
{
   ....

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're the man! I thought it made sense as a Post can `have many` tags and a Tag `belongs to` many Posts. I'll accept when it lets me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `belongsToMany` in your Post model, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
class Post extends Model
{
 ....

  public function tags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

name of pivot tabel and foreign key must be defined in models

class Post extends Model
{
   ....

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class,'post_tag','tag_id',post_id);
}
```

}

class Tags extends Model
{
   ....

```
public function Posts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class,'post_tag','post_id',tag_id);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**I faced this issue, Now I've fixed!**

Post Model:

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class,'post_tag','post_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Tag Model:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Tag::class,'post_tag','post_id', 'tag_id');
}
```